# PySpark: conditional join on calculation

Tags: join, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I got a dataframe that contains locations and their GPS coordinates as longitude and latitude. Now I want to find those locations that are in a range of 500m of another. Therefore I'm trying to join the dataframe with itself - but not doing a full join, but only for those values where the condition is met thus reducing the join overall. But I get this error:

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o341.join. :
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid PythonUDF
>   PythonUDF#(latitude#1655,longitude#1657,lng#1665,ltd#1666),
>   requires attributes from more than one child.

Any idea how to solve that? I know that you can do conditional joins based on the values of columns. But I need it based on a calculation that needs values of 4 columns.

Here's what I did:

The original dataframe looks like this:

```
df
 |-- listing_id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- latitude: float (nullable = true)
 |-- longitude: float (nullable = true)
 |-- price: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- street_address: string (nullable = true)
```

From this I'm creating a copy while renaming some columns. This is a pre-requisite since the join operation doesn't like two columns of the same name.

```
df2 = df.select(df.listing_id.alias('id'), 
                df.street_address.alias('address'),
                df.longitude.alias('lng'),
                df.latitude.alias('ltd'),
                df.price.alias('prc')
               )
```

Then I got the haversine function that calculates the distance between two geo locations in metric kilometers:

```
from math import radians, cos, sin, asin, sqrt

def haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):

    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])

    # haversine formula 
    dlon = lon2 - lon1 
    dlat = lat2 - lat1 
    a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a)) 
    r = 6371 # Radius of earth in kilometers. Use 3956 for miles
    return c * r
```

That's the function I would like to apply to the conditional join:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, col

#berlin_lng = 13.41053
#berlin_ltd = 52.52437

#hav_distance_udf = udf(lambda lng1, ltd1: haversine(lng1, ltd1, berlin_lng, berlin_ltd), FloatType())
#df3 = df.withColumn("distance_berlin", hav_distance_udf(df.longitude, df.latitude))

hav_distance_udf = udf(lambda lng1, ltd1, lng2, ltd2: haversine(lng1, ltd1, lng2, ltd2), FloatType())

in_range = hav_distance_udf(col('latitude'), col('longitude'), col('lng'), col('ltd')) > 0.5

df3 = df.join(df2, in_range)
```

The disabled function withColumn works fine. But the conditional join raises the error see above. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-17100 and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18589

Comment: Ah, zero again. So I need to update my Spark installation?

Comment: At least patch.

Comment: Ok, need to talk to my IT admin then. But do you think this conditional join is a good solution? Or would you propose another one?

Comment: It is a very inefficient solution for a number of reasons (at lest two come to mind). You can do it __a bit__ better by skipping  udf (see for example http://stackoverflow.com/a/42768638/1560062) and as a bonus you won't need to upgrade the cluster but to get a reasonable improvement you'll need to be much smarter than this (and possibly accept some approximations).

Comment: For sure it's not the most efficient way. But what do you mean by much smarter? The solution in your link does a full join to get location1 and location2 in one dataframe and calculates the distance then. The main point is: find all geo-locations in a range to each other. It's making me crazy for days now.

Comment: It depends on the requirements and data but it is to broad for SO IMHO. You can try to narrow the join candidates, wrap one of the existing GIS tools or skip Spark altogether.

Comment: I started using Spark for this because most people try to solve this by merging/joining the original dataset which exceeds the RAM. But realized that I may use R-Trees or K-D-Trees with indexing instead. Going to read that next.